# Unable to run tomcat-8.0.32 from lifteray bundle, liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, liferay, liferay-7

I downloaded liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6 from this [link](https://excellmedia.dl.sourceforge.net/project/lportal/Liferay%20Portal/7.0.5%20GA6/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974.zip) and tried to run the tomcat server with `./startup.sh` and this is the following result :

```
newuser@my-Notebook:~/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32/bin$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/newuser/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/newuser/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/newuser/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/newuser/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/newuser/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

and in the log file, `catalina.out`it gives the error :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/ltiuser/Downloads/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga6-20180320170724974/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga6/tomcat-8.0.32/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: See https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/2c44e28.  Java version must be compatible with Tomcat version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to have JDK 8 running the tomcat. Newest version is not yet supported.

Remove all the existing jdk's :

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

The install java 8 :

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```